# creating object using reflection in windows application

Tags: object, dynamic, reflection, activator

I want to send a function 2 parameters.
1. Type of class
2.Name of object. 
In the new function I want to create the object by the type and the name that was given.
for example:
 private void CreateColumns()
        {
            try
            {
               CreateColumn(typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn),"customerFolderID");
               CreateColumn(typeof(DataGridViewImageColumn),"customerName");
....

private void CreateColumn(Type ColumnType, string ColumnName)
        {
            try
            {
              ...

I thought I can use reflection:
  object Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(ColumnType);

but then how can I do something like this:
Instance ColumnName = new Instance();

The motivation is to replace those lines:

1. DataGridViewTextBoxColumn customerFolderID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
2. dgv_CustomersGrid.Columns.Add(customerFolderID);
3. DataGridViewImageColumn customerName = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
4. dgv_CustomersGrid.Columns.Add(customerName);

is there a way ?
is there any alternative?
maybe I should use dynamic somehow (I don't familiar with this yet) ?